# Let $G$ be a group such that $a^2 = a$ for all $a \in G$, Is $G$ an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to solve this by following:

1. Since $G$ is a group, an inverse exists for every element in $G$.
2. Multiply by inverse to $a$ on both sides of $a^2 = a$.
3. We will get $a = i$, where $i$ is the identity element.
4. This holds true for all $a*$, which implies $G$ contains only one distinct element i.e. $i.$
5. Hence $G$ is abelian.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: Correct, but it seems too easy for an exercise. Are you sure the question didn't say, let $G$ be a group such that $a^2=i$ (the identity element) for all $a\in G,$ is $G$ an Abelian group?

Comment: I solved for a^2 = i. This I could solve easily so I got confused that there might be some subtle point I am missing. Thank you

Comment: If the goal of your question is mainly to ask about correctness of your proof (as opposed to asking for any proof of this fact), you should add ([tag:proof-verification]) tag to make this clear.

Comment: Related: [Trick to proving a group has exactly one idempotent element - Fraleigh p. 48 4.31](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616696).

Comment: If the question was actually $a^2=e$ (the identity element) then it would be a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238171/29335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you are right.

Also, we can get the following.

$$abab=ab$$ 
gives $$aba=a,$$
which gives $$ab=ba=e.$$
Done!

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Yes of course. There are very many similar easy problems.